# Modifying Apache httpd.conf file via C-Panel

Tags: apache, cpanel

I had my websites set up so that if someone types in a URL with upper case letters and/or underscores, like this - MySite/topics/United_States - it will automatically default to mysite/topics/united-states (lower case and dashes instead of underscores).

I've been through some website crashes, moves and reorganization, and I just discovered this feature is no longer working. I haven't been able to access my online httpd.conf file.

However, I think I discovered a way to do it with C-Panel...

Service Configuration > Apache Configuration > Include Editor > Post VirtualHost Include

"Entering information in this text area will add content to the Apache configuration file (httpd.conf) right after the last VirtualHost entry.

"I wish to edit the Post VirtualHost configuration include file for:"

I selected 2.4.18, and it opens a box where I can type in my code. Above the box it says Filename: post_virtualhost_2.con

And this is the code I want to paste in the box:

```
RewriteRule (.?[A-Z]+.) /${tolower:$1} [R]
```

Which brings me to my question. Before I do this I want to make sure I'm not doing something that's going to wreck my site. Does it sound like I'm doing this the right way? And if I somehow mess up this file or paste in the wrong code, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use this rewrite rule in the .htaccess file of a single cPanel account on the server and test it? It will cause a lot less damage in case it does not work and will be easier to revert (just delete the line).

Please make sure that if you add it in an .htaccess, you also start with:

> RewriteEngine On

and then add your rewrite rule.

If you decide to go and edit the global Apache configuration, you should log in the server via SSH and make a copy of the file you are editing:

> /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/post_virtualhost_2.conf

If this breaks your site, you can just restore the original file or remove the changes you made and restart Apache, this should fix it.